# Microsoft office incorrectly claims non office files

Tags: microsoft-office

Ive installed Microsoft office via wine.

Office now believes that some non-office files (my .pub public key file for example) are office files. This understandable, i know .pub is the is the file type for Microsoft publisher files.

In the case of my public key i can easily remove the file ending without any problems, but is this issue likely to cause problems anywhere else on my system?

Comment: Why is Microsoft thinking your public key is a Publisher file bad? What negative behaviour is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be exact, Microsoft Office is claiming some Office file format extensions (like .doc, .docx, .pub etc.).

That really shouldn't cause any problems, except for your user experience in graphical UI.

To my knowledge, .pub is only problematic format. And that extension is not used by (any?) software. Certificates are .csr's, typically openssh files are not handled in Nautilus. Internally OpenSSH do not care about mimetypes or file extension associations.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm mistaken, but I think this will only affect files you open from nautilus (or other file managers), since the system opens files with given programs, like you would do from a terminal.